# Exercise book vs. Composition book

Tags: american-english, british-english

As far as I know, in United States students don't use *exercise books*.

*Image 1. Exercise book*

[image]

[image]

[image]

They use *composition books* instead, which often have "marble" cover and bound through the fold.

[image]

[image]

My question is which wording, *exercise book* or *composition book*, would be preferable if I generally prefer US wording, but I need to describe both US composition books and British (and European) exercise books?

Comment: In USA college campuses, the name I'm familiar with for this kind of stapler-bound lined-paper booklet is a "blue book" (regardless of color) or "exam book", though these will usually have 8-16 pages, while it looks like exercise books have ~80. Some exams will require you to work the problems/write an essay in a blue book and turn it in for grading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any book with blank lined paper (or grid paper) is called a **notebook**. In the US, we do have notebooks with paper covers like those "exercise books", but I'm not familiar with the term "exercise book" so I would probably assume that you were referring to a book filled with exercises for a student to complete (i.e., a [workbook](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/603794/191178)). The term "composition book" is known, but it would seem oddly specific to use it instead of just "notebook".

See also [Common Types of Notebooks Explained](https://www.bluesummitsupplies.com/blogs/resources/common-types-of-notebooks-explained-including-notebook-size-charts)

Comment: I'll add that 'composition book' is not the usual term I heard when I was in school; it was usually 'composition notebook'.

Comment: It's been more years than I'd like to admit, but the label "Composition Book" in the OP's image does look familiar. But I don't think we actually called them that.

Answer (score 5):

An exercise book in the UK is simply any blank notebook for the student to write in. It may be plain, ruled or squared/graphed. I've never heard of the term 'composition book', ever. Even the ones for music class with pre-printed staves were still called exercise books… even though we were learning composition.

They would be most commonly be simply stapled in the middle, like a magazine, but the type of binding doesn't really dictate the name. Generally they're all exercise books, for doing exercises [work] in.

Older students would often transition to loose-leaf ring-binders.
[This from when Noah was a boy; I presume everybody has an iPad or laptop these days;)

Strangely, as soon as you leave school you never use the term exercise book ever again. It seems very school-specific. It's a term I hadn't even thought about in decades, until I saw your question.

Comment: "Strangely, as soon as you leave school you never use the term exercise book ever again." - Indeed, this is quite interesting.

Comment: Yes. It really just occurred to me as I was writing this answer. I used exercise books all the time at school. I have notebooks now - though same as many people, I can now type much faster than I can write, so I don't really use handwriting for much more than a post-it note; but I haven't had an actual 'exercise book' since I left school.

Comment: Agree entirely with the answer, but I would just add that iirc when I was at junior school (in the UK, 1960 - 64) a 'composition' was what in my later school years was called an 'essay'.

Comment: When I was at school in the West of Scotland we called them jotters. I think that was local slang, however, as jotter normally refers to a smaller notebook than this.

Comment: @LaconicDroid - I'm familiar with the term, but I can't recall it being used at school. [Grammar sch. Yorks, N.Eng. 60s/70s]

Comment: Having attended a primary school in Denmark, I can add that the Danish term for exercise books (_kladdehæfte_, literally ‘draft [note]book’) is also one constantly used in school, and then never again. Like you, I hadn’t thought of that word for years and years until I read this question and your answer. I wonder if this is a common phenomenon, that school kids use a particular word for their scribble books that then disappears once they graduate…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The Russian term is "тетрадь" or, colloquially, "тетрадка". The use of this term is not limited to school. If you go study to drive a car or, for example, to theater courses, you would be told to take a "тетрадь" with you. Actually, in Russia, the word notebook ("блокнот") is most often used to describe a very tiny one, the size of your iPhone. You can buy a large notebook, of course, and it will be also called a notebook, but I can't remember any single person with such a notebook. Maybe someone's grandma/grandpa, who use it as a home phonebook.

Comment: To be clear: we don't use the word тетрадь to refer to a "casual" notebook (блокнот). What I mean is that exercise notebooks (тетради) are used more often in everyday life.

Comment: At my school (English Midlands, 1950s/60s) in the junior years we had a 'rough book' for informal notes and an 'exercise book' for each subject, in which we made a formal write-up of each lesson.